# Is is possible to inject a token in an angular component instead of a service?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular6, inject

I have an injectionToken i have provided in my angular module like

```
const OpayApiKeyToken = new InjectionToken<string | undefined>('opay-apiKey');

....
export class AngularOpayModule {
  static forRoot(apiKey: string): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: AngularOpayModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: OpayApiKeyToken, useValue: apiKey },
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

. I want to import it straight into a component like this

```
  constructor(@Inject(OpayApiKeyToken) apiKey: string) {}
```

But I get this error if I Inject it into a component

```
compiler.js:215 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for
```

It works when I inject it into a service though

Is there a way to this?

Comment: It works if i import it into a service

Comment: Where and how did you define OpayApiKeyToken, and provide its value? Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.